# Ubuntu MAAS & Juju redundancy

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, openstack-autopilot, cluster

I am planing to setup an Ubuntu cloud based on MAAS and Juju. It looks promising so far, but I didn't understand how it handles redundancy.

[MAAS split network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr4MR.png)

There are seven physical servers. Two of them have two NICs. One of this machine is the MAAS machine. I'll call it server 1 here. The second machine is called server 2. Both machines have access to the public and private network. All other five servers with one NIC are attached to the private network (servers 3-7). If one of the nodes (server 3-7) fails, another node will overtake the services to keep things running.

1. How is traffic routed to the public network (internet)? Is traffic routed from server 4 over server 1 or 2 to the public network?
2. What is the blue symbol in the image? I thought, that the servers 3-7 are only connected to the private network.
3. What happens if the MAAS machine (server 1) fails? Does server 2 spawn a redundant MAAS service to keep things running?
4. What happens if server 2 fails?
5. If server 1 or 2 are used to route the traffic to the public network and one fails, how does this affect registered DNS entries for domains pointing to the IP address of the failed server?

Thank you!

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!